# TLS v 1.2 with android, websockets and node.js

Tags: android, node.js, ssl, websocket

I am trying to send some data from an android (4.1) application to a node.js https server, to do so I use Gottox's socket.io with Weberknecht websockets.

I have achieved to communicate the aplication and the server over TLS 1.0 with the cipher suite

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Adding it to options of the server:

```
var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync(...),
   cert: fs.readFileSync(...),
   ciphers:('AES128-SHA'),
}
```

But I want to use the cipher suite of TLS v1.2

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

That is supposed to be supported in android 4.1, so I have changed the ciphers option to

```
ciphers:('ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA'),
```

Moreover, to make it work, in the WebSocketConnection.java of Weberknecht websockets, I have change the Sockets to SSLSockets, so I can enable all the cipher suites supported by android with this code:

```
socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
String[] suites = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
```

But it doesn't work, if I delete the ciphers option in the server or I put again the first cipher suite it does, but only over TLS 1.0.

The stack error is:

```
03-14 16:44:01.215: W/System.err(3762): io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
03-14 16:44:01.220: W/System.err(3762):     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
03-14 16:44:01.220: W/System.err(3762):     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:283)
03-14 16:44:01.220: W/System.err(3762):     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
03-14 16:44:01.225: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
03-14 16:44:01.230: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
03-14 16:44:01.230: W/System.err(3762):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
03-14 16:44:01.230: W/System.err(3762):     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:304)
03-14 16:44:01.230: W/System.err(3762):     ... 2 more
```

I have been going through the WebSocketHandshake.java and IOConnection.java but I don't find the source of the problem...

Any suggestion?

If you want, you can check the code of the client here:

https://github.com/Javi44/LocAALTOn/tree/WebSockets-Gottox

EDIT:

This is the method that is raising the exception:

```
private void handshake() {
    URL url;
    String response;
    URLConnection connection;
    try {
        setState(STATE_HANDSHAKE);
        url = new URL(IOConnection.this.url.toString() + SOCKET_IO_1);
        connection = url.openConnection();
        if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection) connection)
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        }
        connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(connectTimeout);

        /* Setting the request headers */
        for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty((String) entry.getKey(),
                    (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(stream);
        response = in.nextLine();
        String[] data = response.split(":");
        sessionId = data[0];
        heartbeatTimeout = Long.parseLong(data[1]) * 1000;
        closingTimeout = Long.parseLong(data[2]) * 1000;
        protocols = Arrays.asList(data[3].split(","));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error(new SocketIOException("Error while handshaking", e));
    }
}
```

May be the problem that is using a url connection instead of a SSLSocket? Would be possible to change the url connection to something with the same functionality but using SSLSockets?

Comment: Where do you have the information from that Android 4.1 supports TLS 1.2? My Google Galaxy Nexus on 4.1.2 does not support TLS 1.2.

Comment: I read it here in stackoverflow, but to be sure of it, I printed out the cipher suites returned by the method getSupportedCipherSuites() and the suite that I try to use is between them.